# Ajax simple call doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm using AJAX for the first time and I'm struggling to make it work...
In my view I have a table generated by my controller. 
View (vueConsigne.php)

```
    <tbody>
    <?php echo $tab_plan; ?>
    </tbody>
```

Controller (control_vueCsn.php):

```
foreach($lesPlanifs as $laPlanif){
    $tab_plan.= "<tr><td>".$laPlanif->getClass().
            "</td><td>".$laPlanif->get("dateHeureDebut")->format('d-m-Y   H:i:s').
            "</td><td>".$laPlanif->get("dateHeureFin")->format('d-m-Y H:i:s').
            "</td><td>"." ".
            "</td><td>"."Recurrence : ".$val. " " .$unit .
            "</td><td>"."n/c".
            "</td><td><button name=\"suppPlaniSusp\" onclick=\"call_supp_bdd(".$laPlanif->get("id").",".$laPlanif->getClass().")\"><img src=\"../img/close_pop.png\" id=\"suppPlanif\" name=\"suppPlanBtn\" width=\"30\" height=\"30\"></button></td></tr>";
```

That generated table, as you can see on last line, has a button on which I want to fire my Ajax function (call_supp_bdd) when it's clicked. I want to pass to the function 2 parameters,the class name and the id of the object corresponding to the table line.
Here is the ajax function in vueConsigne.php :

```
    function call_supp_bdd(int,c)
    {

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)    //  Objet standard
        {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();     //  Firefox, Safari, ...
        }
        else      //  Internet Explorer
        {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","../control/suppPlanif.php?q="+int+"&c="+c,true);
        xmlhttp.send();


        }
```

And finally here is my PHP file called by Ajax (suppPlanif.php) :

```
    <?php
    /**
    * Created by PhpStorm.
    * User: ymakouf
    * Date: 07/08/2015
    * Time: 10:14
    */
    $q = intval($_GET['q']);
    $c = intval($_GET['c']);
    $cnx = new CNX();
    $dbh = $cnx->connexion();
    $req = $dbh->prepare("DELETE * FROM".$c."WHERE id =".$q);
    $req->execute();

    ?>
```

I just tried to replace it with just this instruction

```
    <?php
    echo "sucess";
    ?>
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: When you have jQuery included on page, why not use `$.ajax`?

Comment: What doesn't work? You're not really doing anything.

Comment: also `int` is reserved keyword, don't use it as function parameter.

Comment: **1)** `"DELETE * FROM".$c."WHERE id =".$q` is wrong. There must be `space` after `FROM` and before `WHERE`. **2)** Don't use `int` as variable name. **3)** What after `xmlhttp.send()`?. You should see this [**example**](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first).

Comment: Where is your selectors (ID, Class) for your response? After Ajax processed and its response need to be embed into your DOM

Answer (score 0):

When you're loading jQuery then please use jquery's simple syntax. Dont do it manually.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  type: "GET"
}).done(function( response ) {
  alert( response );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're **not doing anything with the response**, you need to add an `onload` callback for processing the response you get.

Here's how you could do it:

```
function call_supp_bdd(int,c)
{

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)    //  Objet standard
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();     //  Firefox, Safari, ...
    }
    else      //  Internet Explorer
    {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","../control/suppPlanif.php?q="+int+"&c="+c,true);

    //NOTE: this code will be executed AFTER send(), it's asynchronous
    xmlhttp.onload = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            alert('Request response: ' + xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
        else {
            alert('Request failed. Status:' + xmlhttp.status);
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Or, if **you've included jQuery**, you can just use `$.ajax()` which makes things simpler:

```
function call_supp_bdd(int, c) {
    $.ajax({
            url: "../control/suppPlanif.php?q=" + int + "&c=" + c,
            type: "GET"
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            alert('Request response: ' + data);
        });
}
```

Comment: Ok I'll use $.ajax. I'm not sure i understant this part of the function :       .done(function (data){});         What does it do a part from showing an alert ? And what does the parameter "data" refers to. Actually i don't want to display anything with my function. I want to stay on same page, just delete the corresponding element in the database....

Comment: The alerts I wrote are just placeholders for what you need to do, you can replace them with the code you need to apply for removing items. Also, `data` is just a name for the variable that contains the **server's response text**, you can rename it to whatever you want and it will contain whatever you sent back from the server.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information. it still looks like my function is not called. Why ? I added : alert('in the fct'); just before $.ajax({}) to check if i was even passing by the function and no alert when i cliked the button. Is my call correct ?                                                                                                    `"</td><td><button name=\"suppPlaniSusp\" onclick=\"call_supp_bdd(".$laPlanif->get("id").",".$laPlanif->getClass().")\"><img src=\"../img/close_pop.png\" id=\"suppPlanif\" name=\"suppPlanBtn\" width=\"30\" `code`height=\"30\"></button></td></tr>";`

Comment: @YaniOz You should edit your question and add how you call the function, avoid posting long code in comments, it's hard to read.